# Stop task or thread while it's executing some external method in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, concurrency

I'm working on some JavaFX application. On one point I execute some external method which sometimes takes a lot of time to finish. That's why I decided to create a `Task`, run it in new thread and let user stop it.

The problem is I couldn't find any way to cancel execution of that method. I cannot really modify that method to check if task `isCanceled` or change it in any other way.

I also tried calling `thread.interrupt()` with no luck.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Sorry to bear bad news, but you may not have any options here.  If the owner of the external method does not want to cooperate for multithreaded environment, there are no language concepts to make them do so.  Interrupt in Java is really just a suggestion.  If the code in external library does not pay any attention to it (or swallows it), it will be ignored.

Comment: What is the external method?

Comment: You could try `Thread.stop()`. However it could potentially be unsafe which is why it has been deprecated. But despite of that it will probably continue to work for a long time. It was deprecated 15 years ago and there are still no plans to remove it from the Java API.

Comment: @Alexander Pogrebnyak thank You. Could You give me some quick tip how to write my own methods to support multi-threading? I've got some methods which could take a lot time to execute and would like to make it possible for user to interrupt them. Any better solution then checking 'isInterrupted' flag?   
@Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot it's `toObj()` method from https://github.com/miho/JCSG/blob/cb606b3fc112d69f6697c9061d6e193359374b80/src/main/java/eu/mihosoft/vrl/v3d/CSG.java .    
@SpiderPig 15 years ago?! I didn't want to use this method, but if there's no other choice... Thank You.

Comment: You could use a volatile boolean variable that you set to true if you want the thread to end. Then you have to check the state of that variable inside your thread in regular intervals. Another option is to use `java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue`. Then you can use the `poll` method inside your thread and terminate it if `poll` returns a value other then null. In your main thread you can then call `offer` to "send" a termination request to the other thread. Concurrent queues are often used to allow different threads to communicate safely.

Comment: I just checked when `Thread.stop` was deprecated. And it was in December 98, when Java 1.2 was released. So over 17 years ago.

Comment: Do ***not*** use `Thread.stop()`. It is deprecated because it is unsafe and can "cause arbitrary behavior". Java values back-compatibility over pretty much everything, so the method won't be removed for that reason, but you should not take that as a sign that it is safe to use. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: Second *not* to use `Thread.stop`.  I've looked at `toObj` source code, and if you don't mind refactoring it, I would check the `Thread.isInterrupted` at the start of each loop iteration, and throw `InterruptedException` if it's the case.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak, James_D, SpiderPig - thanks guys. Do You know any other solution to make method 'interruptable' then checking some boolean variable and reacting to it? In my opinion, it doesn't look too handy for programmer to do this it in every loop iteration ever.